# How to find the max angle the pendulum reaches during oscillation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, angular-velocity

I have a pendulum that is swinging with no loss of total energy. Is it possible to find out the maximum angle, $\:\theta_{o}$ to which the pendulum reaches, based on only the following information?

Known variables:

- $\theta$ : The current angle shown in the image below
- $\omega_{\theta}$ : The angular velocity at $\theta$
- L : Length of the rope
- g : acceleration due to gravity

[image: Pendulum swinging]

Comment: How come $g$ is the gravitational constant? Is it the acceleration due to gravity?

Comment: Use conservation of energy instead of acceleration or velocity.

Comment: @lee I made a mistake, I have already corrected it. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Which is this formula: $$x=x_0+vt$$ Is it this one: $$v=v_0+at$$

Comment: @lee its this one displacement = (initial displacement) + (velocity)(time_elapsed)

Comment: I meant, has it got any significance here?

Comment: @lee i guess not, it's just my thought flow. I will just remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the concept of total energy is a constant.

The two components of the energy:

$$
 E_k(\theta) = \frac{1}{2} m v(\theta)^2 =  \frac{1}{2} m (L\dot{\theta})^2 =  \frac{1}{2} m L^2 \omega_\theta^2 \\
V(\theta) = m g h(\theta) = m g L (1 - \cos(\theta)
$$
Thus
$$
E_k(\theta) +V(\theta) =\frac{1}{2} m L^2 \omega_\theta^2 + m g L (1 - \cos\theta) = \text{constant}.
$$

When the pendulum reaches the maximam angle $\theta_0$, its speed vanishes:

$$
\frac{1}{2} m L^2 \omega_\theta^2 + m g L (1 - \cos\theta) =m g L (1 - \cos\theta_0 ) .
$$

Which is the equation to find  $\theta_0$.